# What is causing flutter doctor "plug in error "

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm working under Android Studio 4.0 , also  have latest  version of  flutter  installed ,im getting  the error message **!] Android Studio✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality. ** Although I am installed both  Dart  and flutter plugin , how to  fix this error

Answer (score 0):

First, if you haven't download [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio). Then go to configure then plugins than find the Flutter plugin and install it. [Here's the flutter document on doing this.](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=androidstudio)